# How to decode .ogg opus to int16 NumPy array with librosa?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, ogg, librosa, mozilla-deepspeech

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to transcribe Telegram audio messages, using Mozillas speech-to-text engine [deepspeech](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.4/).

Using `*.wav` in 16bit 16khz works flawless.

I want to add `*.ogg` opus support, since Telegram uses this format for it's audio messages.

#### What I have tried so far

I have tried [pyogg](https://pypi.org/project/PyOgg/) and [soundfile](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/) so far, with no luck.

Soundfile could outright not read the opus format and pyogg is a pain to install without conda. I had really weird moments where it literally crashed python.

Right now, I'm trying librosa with mixed results.

```py
data, sample_rate = librosa.load(path)

tmp = np.array(data, np.float16)

tmp.dtype = np.int16

int16 = np.array(tmp, dtype=np.int16)

metadata = model.sttWithMetadata(int16)
```

Deepspeech really likes `np.int16`. `model.sttWithMetadata` is essentially the call for the transcriber.

Right now, it does transcribe something, but nowhere near anything resembling what I speak in my audio message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

librosa returns an array floats in range `-1.0` to `1.0`. In **int16** the maximum value is `32767`. So you have to multiply to scale the signal, then convert to **int16**.

```
data, sample_rate = librosa.load(path)

int16 = (data * 32767).astype(np.int16)

metadata = model.sttWithMetadata(int16)
```

**Quick explanation why 32767:**

In [16-bit computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit_computing), an integer can store 216 distinct values.

That means, unsigned integers can range from 0 to 65,535 and the two complement representation from -32,768 to 32,767. This means, a processor with 16-bot memory addresses can access 64KB (or 64 * 1024 = 65,436 unique addresses)  of memory at a time.

If our float array then has values, ranging from -1.0 to 1.0, we scale the signal by a factor of 32,767 to make it compatible with the 16 bit addresses your deepspeech model expects to find.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. I played it with `sounddevice as sd` calling `sd.play(int16, sample_rate)` and it's plays the file as int16